# script not running in terminal, but working in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea

When I run my machine learning script from IntelliJ run button it's running properly but when I run it using the terminal it's not running.

I used the following commands to set my virtual env first:

```
cd C:\Users\V753961\virtual\scripts
activate python.exe
```

And after activating the virtual environment I used the following commands to run my script:

```
python <path to my script> --db_user *** --db pass ***
```

`--db_user` and `--db_pass` are my parameters.

Comment: Can you add some more information. Like the output from the terminal or errors that you're seeing. 

I also notice that there's no underscore '_' in the command you put in. But maybe that's just a typo.

Comment: when you activate your virtual env do you see (venv) behind command line? if not it means venv does not activate properly so you cant run script